# Generate JWT with certificate thumbprint with JSON Web Token Handler for .Net

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I'm starting a new task where I have to process thumbprint from JWT. We use JSON Web Token Handler For the Microsoft .Net Framework. There is already an implementation used in tests that generates JWT without x5t filed in header. It looks like this:

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
      var securityKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Any.Array<byte>(1024));
      var desc = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
      {
        TokenIssuerName = "MSI",
        Lifetime = new Lifetime(null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10)),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"),
      };

      var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("scope", "msi_unsapi_presence.watch"));
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("scope", "msi_unsapi_location.watch"));
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("scope", "msi_unsapi_groupmgt.read"));
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("scope", "msi_unsapi_groupmgt.write"));
      var jwtToken = handler.CreateToken(desc);
      return jwtToken;
```

And the token it produces: `{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}.{"scope":["msi_unsapi_presence.watch","msi_unsapi_location.watch","msi_unsapi_groupmgt.read","msi_unsapi_groupmgt.write"]}` I try to set   AttachedReference property of  SecurityTokenDescriptor as the following `AttachedReference = new X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Any.Array<byte>(1024))` to have x5t field filled in the token (I don't care about the exact value, I just need it to exist in token for test purpose) but the token produced still doesn't have this field set. How can I generate the token with not empty x5t filed in header, preferably modifying the existing code?

Comment: i'm not familial with your JwtSecurityTokenHandler class but what i did in my implementation is create my own jsonWebTokenFormat that implement the ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> (implement the protect/ unprotect method)

the trick is that in the class you will need to call JwtPayload() which is a superclass of Dictionary<string,string>() so you can add your x5t field to any value you want as long as it's json formatted. then you will need to condifure your JwtSecurityTokenHandler to use your new JwtFormat then proceed with your Identity and claims.

Comment: I cannot modify JwtSecurityTokenHandler class, for it's a library class (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/)  And I really cannot find in what way I can configure it to my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the implementation for your customJsonWebTokenFormat :

You can really add anything to it with the `payload.add()`.

```cs
public class yourJsonWebTokenFormat: ISecureDataFormat < AuthenticationTicket > {
    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data) {
        DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime expires = notBefore + TimeSpan.FromHours(1); //validity timer.
        SigningCredentials cred = new SigningCredentials(); // your signing credentials.
        JwtHeader header = new JwtHeader(cred);
        header.add("x5t", "your value");
        JwtPayload payload = newJwtPayload(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Issuer"], data.Properties.Dictionary["audience"], data.Identity.Claims, notBefore, expires);
        payload.add("x5t", "your x5t to json property");
        var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwt = handler.WriteToken(jwtToken);
        return jwt;
    }
}
```

then in your OAuth Config :

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() {
    // provider configuration, token authentication expiracy, etc...
    Provider = new SampleAuthorizationServerProvider()
    AccessTokenFormat = new JsonWebTokenFormat()
};
```

Requesting a token will now call your `yourJsonWebTokenFormat.protect()` method.

You should set the identity you built in your sample in a AuthenticationTicket in your own OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.

Something like this :

```
public class SampleAuthorizationServerProvider: OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider {
    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context) {
        // do AD check or other stuff needed to validate the user here
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props); // props here is a AuthenticationProperties Dictionnary with other stuff that you want in your JwtToken
        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context) {
        //do some check...
        context.Validated();
    }
}
```

So you end up with 2 classes you need to implement : `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>`
and
`OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`

Comment: 1) When I add anything to payload, the value is not added to jwt header. 2) I didn't want to create jwt from scratches but to use existing method. For now I just downcasted CreateToken results to JwtSecurityToken and added value to header like to a regular dictionary, which is ugly

Comment: not only is it ugly but the token you get should now be invalid. the CreateToken is responsible in adding the Signature to the token. if you modify it afterward i don't think the signature will get updated. so your signature will not match the payload anymore.

Comment: all the same it doesn't resolve the problem that this filed is not in header with your approach

Comment: actually it does, what can be done with the Body/ payload work the same with the header too so header.add("x5t ","your Value"); will add a field with x5t in the header.

Comment: it doesn't differ from simply setting the value as I've written earlier. The signature seems to be updated the same way.

Comment: I think, the difference is that CreateToken() Vs WriteToken() where WriteToken will encode / build the token and sign it while CreateToken() will generate a plain Token from the security Descriptor.

the rest is juste an approach to create a token with Owin.

Comment: Well, actually my primary need is a raw token. In some tests I need to have a string representation, in some - I don't. All the same - thanks for your help. I will try to figure out which implementation suits me better.